# Process order form with php to send email

Tags: php, forms

I have the following code:

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="itemsTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="item-row">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemCode[]" value="" class="input-medium" id="itemCode"
                               tabindex="1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemDesc[]" value="" class="input-large" id="itemDesc"
                               readonly="readonly"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="itemQty[]" value="" class="input-mini" id="itemQty" tabindex="2"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-append"><span class="add-on">&#8364;</span>
                        <input
                                name="itemPrice[]"
                                class=" input-small"
                                id="itemPrice"
                                type="text"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-append"><span class="add-on">&#8364;</span><input
                                name="itemLineTotal[]" class=" input-small" id="itemLineTotal" type="text"
                                readonly="readonly"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

What is the best way to process the inputs via php to send the order via email nicley formated into a table?  This is an order form and I need to to simply be sent to an email once complete

Here is my processing code:

```
<?php 
$to = $_REQUEST['xxx'] ; 
$from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
$name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
$headers = "From: $from"; 
$subject = "Web Contact Data"; 

$fields = array(); 
$fields{"itemCode"} = "Code"; 
$fields{"itemDesc"} = "Description"; 
$fields{"itemPrice"} = "Price"; 

$body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; 

foreach($fields as $a => $b){
$body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); 
} 

$headers2 = "From: noreply@example.com"; 
$subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
$autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.oursite.com";


 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body); 
 if($send){
header( "Location:index.php" );
} else {
    print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please try again"; 
} 
?>
```

This code is not working please help

Comment: "Is not working". Some more details what is not working could help you to get a answer.

Answer (score 1):

To process a form this way you need to have a form element somewhere in your markup to process.

```
<form method="POST" action="yourSecondScript.php">
    your first markup here
    <input type="submit">
<form>
```

Then to make the email nice with tables you need to set the email headers to html.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['Name'] . ">\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is

```
$to = $_REQUEST['xxx'] ;
```

coming from? My guess is that you can set it to fixed as you probably don't need a dynamic e-mail to address, so something like:

```
$to = 'myname@mydomain.com';
```

But as Michael mentioned in a reaction to your question, we cannot be sure until you tell us which part is not working / what errors you receive and so on..

Comment: I recieve an email but only Code: Description: Price: no data is sent in email

Comment: When you echo the $body var, do you see the proper data? If not, you know where to look.